# Stop iframe from loading src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

In one page I have multiple iframes as blocks with drag and drop functionality. So when I am dragging one block, at that time it is loading again. Due to the loading, my previous changes in that block has gone.

How to stop this loading?

Comment: Where's the code? We can't help with your poor description

Comment: ui.item.find('iframe').stop();  it is not working properly

Comment: if you use animation only stop function works.. one more if you used ajax concept or any other for loading the iframe content, which means that use to load a "call back" for the function it will works to load a content in iframe without bugs..